# Error - Rendering multiple instances in react search component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, jsx

I am building a search component where the user types in the value and it filters through some dummy data and renders the result for the user to see. The problem is when I type in one character in the search field i get the entire array of data on every character I type. So for example there are 4 data strings in the array so if I type in two characters in the search bar then my result is 8.

[Here is the code and the problem duplicated](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-cartwright-q8rqy?file=/src/App.js): Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is below, basically, the code was loading in an extra map from `CompanyInfoList component`. I also had a useContext that was not needed in the same component, so i removed it and replaced `results.map` from `useContext setState hook` to `filtered.map`. filtered was the prop that needed to be passed down from `CompSearch` to `CompanyInfoList.` The last change I made was to delete the `RenderList component` and remove return `RenderList` in the `serachList component` to `CompanyInfoList`

CompSearch.js

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from "react";
import CompanyInfoList from "./CompanyInfoList";
import { CompListContext } from "./CompListContext";

const CompSerach = () => {
    // const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [results, setResults] = useContext(CompListContext);
    const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");
    const [searchShow, setSearchShow] = useState(false);

    const filtered = results.filter((res) => {
        return (
        res.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
        res.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
        res.date.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
        res.amount.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
      
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchField(e.target.value);
        if (e.target.value === "") {
          setSearchShow(false);
        } else {
          setSearchShow(true);
        }
      };

      function searchList() {
        if (searchShow) {
          return <CompanyInfoList filtered={filtered} />;
        }
      }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="search"
          placeholder="search Company Title"
          //   input="input"
          //   value={input}
          onChange={handleChange}
          // onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      {searchList()}
    </>
  );
};

export default CompSerach;
```

CompanyInfoList.js

```
import Results from "./Results";

const CompanyInfoList = ({ filtered }) => {
  const fltr = filtered.map((result) => (
    <Results
      key={result.id}
      name={result.name}
      employee={result.employee}
      date={result.date}
      amount={result.amount}
    />
  ));
  return <div>{fltr}</div>;
};
export default CompanyInfoList;
```